# Styling existing UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

So I have a `UITextField` in Interface Builder and I'm trying to change the border.

In my `initWithNibName` method this is what I do -

```
        self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
        NSLog(@"SEARCH BAR : %@", self.searchBar);
        self.searchBar.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        self.searchBar.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
        self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

This doesn't work because the searchBar is null, which is strange because I'm in the initWithNibName method.

How do I change the border of this textField?

Comment: put it in "viewDidLoad" method

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it too early. From the `UIViewController` [doc](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller’s view is accessed. **If you want to
>   perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded,
>   override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there**.